# SSH Connection Closed after changing sources.list

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, update, digital-ocean

working on a Ubuntu 19.04 Digital Ocean server. After updating `sources.list` to focal, so I could update repositories and install certbot, I found my self locked out of the server with the message `Connection refused`.
Managed to enter through Digital Ocean Recovery Console, and checked all ssh configs, `authorized_keys` files, everything, and could not find an error.
What I did found was ssh brute force attack against the server, so I change the port.
Afterwards I start getting the message `Connection Closed` when trying to connect to the server via terminal.
Here I leave `ssh_config`, `sshd_config`, `sources.list`, the output of connecting with ssh, and the output of making `apt update` inside the recovery console.
`ssh_config`

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#bunch of commented options
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

`sshd_config`

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port <PORT>
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication no

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no 

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin yes
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

`sources.list`, now changed with groovy but originally changed with focal

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy universe
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy universe
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates universe
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy multiverse
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy multiverse
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu groovy partner

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security multiverse
```

on server, via recory console, `sudo apt update`

```
[...]
Err:5  groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.148.71 80]
Err:6  Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.67.148.71 80]
Hit:7  disco InRelease
Ign:8  disco InRelease
Err:9  disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
[...]
```

on client, `ssh -vvvv -i <key> <user>@<ip>`

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ivangk/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <IP> is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to <IP> [<IP>] port <PORT>.
debug1: Connection established.
[...]
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection closed by <IP> port <PORT>
```

I am lost at what can be causing this problem. If I do `lsof -i:<PORT>` I get the correct port that I configured active, and ssh is active via `systemctl status sshd`.

Comment: 19.04 has been end of life for three years. Upgrade. And deal with brute force attacks by disallowing password authentication and fail2ban, or similar - not obscurity.

Comment: @vidarlo hi! I had password authentication disabled, but enabled it to see if the problem was the key pair authentication, alas, the problem remains

Comment: You probably have external firewall blocking your new port. But again: update to a sane version.

Comment: hi @vidarlo thanks for the comments! nope, I have allowed the new port through ufw, and still this is happening. Should have added that to the post.

Comment: How about external firewalls?

Comment: good question, I will check Digital Ocean for that, though there are other servers running without a problem... I think something of the focal update broke ssh

Comment: @vidarlo sorry for the delay, happy new year! checked and the droplet has no firewall configured from DO... I think I'll recover the files and start with a clean one